# How to create a dictionary out of random values from two lists?

Tags: python, pandas, macos, dataframe

Context: I have two lists of unequal size; `names` holds family members' names and `chores` holds a much longer list of, well, chores. I am writing a program to randomly assign each chore to a family member, so that the everyone gets the same number of chores (or at least with +1/-1). I've thought of a few possible ways of going about this, at least in theory. One way would be to simply shuffle the list of `chores`, split the list evenly into `n` new lists, and assign one of these smaller lists to each family member. I could also loop through the list of chores, assigning each family member a chore on each pass through until all chores have been assigned to a family member.

I've had trouble finding specific operations or examples to help work through this; is there a specific workflow I should consider?.

Comment: The "easiest" way is to simply assign all chores to the family member you hate the most and claim "bad luck"...

Comment: Btw I suggest that the chore of providing example data for testing should be done by you.

Comment: Oh and to answer the title question: Yes, of course it's possible. That just clutters the title.

Comment: @Manuel You are really on a tear here with all of the comments. I don't think I asked anyone to source their own sample data.

Comment: I'm at a loss here, and quite confused why this question's been closed. Not to mention closing it after we've already arrived at a workable solution. A solution we wouldn't have arrived at if the question did truly need additional 'details or clarity'. Since we have a workable solution, thanks to these wonderful contributors, I'm not going to edit or delete the question, which could hold value for someone else.

Comment: In the future please [post code that shows the problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). It is very difficult to understand code described in prose. Look at the answers you've got; would they be as helpful if they included no code at all? The same is true of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup stolen from pakpe's answer:

```
import random

names = ['John', 'Ashley', 'Debbie']
chores = ['cook', 'clean', 'shop', 'pay bills', 'wash car', 'mow lawn', 'walk dog', 'drive kids']
```

Solution 1, distributing the chores evenly:

```
random.shuffle(names)
random.shuffle(chores)
assignments = {name: chores[i::len(names)]
               for i, name in enumerate(names)}
```

Sample result:

```
{'Debbie': ['wash car', 'clean', 'shop'],
 'Ashley': ['walk dog', 'mow lawn', 'cook'],
 'John': ['drive kids', 'pay bills']}
```

Solution 2, perhaps slightly easier but uneven (posted before they changed the question):

```
assignments = {name: [] for name in names}
for chore in chores:
    assignments[random.choice(names)].append(chore)
```

Sample result:

```
{'Debbie': ['mow lawn', 'pay bills', 'shop', 'cook'],
 'Ashley': [],
 'John': ['wash car', 'walk dog', 'drive kids', 'clean']}
```

(First try, Ashley really got that lucky.)

Comment: @Nick I think it's better to include everyone in the dict.

Comment: Good point, I should have considered that Ashley might get lucky again! :)

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear, but the chores need to be distributed as evenly as possible! Sorry, but nobody will be getting away without at least a few chores!!

Comment: @Manuel would be be possible to set a minimum number of chores for each family member as the quotient of the number of chores divided by the number of family members?

Comment: @HoganMarhoefer Sure, but why? Solution 1 already achieves that.

Comment: You're right, my friend. Please disregard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` + `cycle` or `zip_longest` to pair people with chores depending upon whether you have fewer chores or people. If you have more chores than people, this will still create a DataFrame of all people, some with `None` as their chore.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle, zip_longest
from random import shuffle

names = ['John', 'Ashley', 'Debbie']
chores = ['cook', 'clean', 'shop', 'pay bills', 'wash car', 'mow lawn', 'walk dog', 'drive kids']
```

---

```
shuffle(chores)
shuffle(names)

if len(names) <= len(chores):
    data = zip(cycle(names), chores)
else:
    data = zip_longest(names, chores)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'chore'])

#     name       chore
#0    John    wash car
#1  Ashley    mow lawn
#2  Debbie       clean
#3    John    walk dog
#4  Ashley  drive kids
#5  Debbie        shop
#6    John        cook
#7  Ashley   pay bills
```

And now you can do whatever you want with `pandas`, like aggregate to a list.

```
df.groupby('name').chore.agg(list)
#name
#Ashley              [wash car, cook, clean]
#Debbie                     [shop, mow lawn]
#John      [walk dog, drive kids, pay bills]
#Name: chore, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
import random
names = ['John', 'Ashley', 'Debbie']
chores = ['cook', 'clean', 'shop', 'pay bills', 'wash car', 'mow lawn', 'walk dog', 'drive kids']

ratio = len(chores)//len(names)
assignments = {}
for name in names:
    assignments[name] = random.sample(chores, ratio)

print(assignments)

#{'John': ['mow lawn', 'pay bills'], 'Ashley': ['cook', 'walk dog'], 'Debbie': ['mow lawn', 'shop']}
```

If you wants all chores to be assigned and no duplicate chores, here is a solution:

```
import random
names = ['John', 'Ashley', 'Debbie']
chores = ['cook', 'clean', 'shop', 'pay bills', 'wash car', 'mow lawn', 'walk dog', 'drive kids']

random.shuffle(chores)
chunck = len(chores)//len(names)
remainder = len(chores)%len(names)

#distribute even chunks of chores amongst names
assignments = {}
for idx, name in enumerate(names):
    assignments[name] = chores[idx*chunck: idx*chunck+chunck]

#distribure remaining chores amongst names
if remainder != 0:
    remaining_chores = chores[-remainder:]
    for i in range(len(remaining_chores)):
        assignments[names[i]] += [remaining_chores[i]]
    
print(assignments)
```

Comment: I am noticing two things off the bat... it seems two of the eight 'chores' are missing from your output, and 'mow lawn' appears twice in the output but only once in the chores list.

Comment: @HoganMarhoefer See my amended answer.

Comment: About the second solution: Poor John, always the first (possibly even only) to get a remaining chore. Not fair.

Comment: @Manuel I updated the answer and fixed the issue with the zero remainder.